# Emacs Regexp syntax clarification

Tags: regular-expressions

I am a bit confused on some aspects of Emacs regexps. Specifically with the 
paragraph on [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/emacs-regular-expression-syntax.html) page

> 1. ‘`\W`’ matches a character which is not within a word
> 2. ‘`\B`’ matches characters which are not a word boundary
> 3. ‘`` \` ``’ matches the beginning of the whole input
> 4. ‘`\'`’ matches the end of the whole input

Can someone give examples of where each of these might apply?

Also suppose for a generic regexp *R*, if I augment it as `^`*R*`$` what does that mean? Does it mean it matches the expression at the beginning and end of sentences. Elsewhere on this site I have seen the regexp `^\s-$` being used to detect blank lines.

I understand each of `^` and `$` in isolation but not when used together

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`^` matches an empty string at a beginning of a line, `$` at an end of a line. Therefore, `^R$` matches a line that contains the single character R.

To experiment, you can try

```
(string-match "\\W" "abc d")
```

The backslash needs to be doubled in double quotes.

It returns 3, because the space is not within a word (and the first character has index 0).

`\B` matches inside a word, so for example, the "b" would match in `" abc"`.

I'm not sure how to explain the very beginning and end of the input. `string-match` will always return 0 for `` \` `` and the length of the string for `\'`. So, if the string contains no newlines, `^` and `` \` `` are equivalent, as are `$` and `\'`. If the string contains newlines, `^` matches at each line's start and `$` at each line's end, while `` \` `` still matches at the very beginning of the string only, and similarly for `\'` and the very end.